# Javascript Regular Expression is working fine first time but not second time, working again for 3rd time and not for 4th and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Javascript Regular Expression is working fine first time but not second time, working again for 3rd time and not for 4th  and so on :(

Script :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var reg = /[^\w]/gi;
    function checkNonWordChars() {
        var str = $("#TestTextbox").val();
        if (reg.test(str)) {
            alert('!!! Non-Word Char Exists !!!');
        }
        else {
            alert('input accepted');
        }
    }    
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="TestTextbox"  />
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="checkNonWordChars();" />
```

If I click on button once, it will fire an alert saying that  “!!! Non-Word Char Exists !!!” but if I click it again, it will fire an alert saying “input accepted” :(

Comment: do you have any blur/change/focus handlers on that text box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

Use the constructor rather than the literal notation:

```
var reg = new RegExp('[^\w]','gi');
```

More about differences between the two here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirect=no

**OPTION 2**

Mark the end of the string with a `$` sign:

```
var reg = /[^\w$]/gi;
```

**OPTION 3**

If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the `exec` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the `substring` of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property 
(`test` will also advance the lastIndex property).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Therefore, in your case the test will work only 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... time.

Only in Firefox 3 there is a flag `y` , when specified `exec` always starts from 0 not `lastIndex` but this is probably not useful in your case.

You can remove the `g` flag.

Comment: OPTION 1 works fine, not OPTION 2, Anyways thank you for your post

Comment: Your regex in option 2 is wrong. You are just adding the "$" character to the character class, you wanted `var reg = /[^\w]$/gi;`. But anyway, I think this would not be what the OP wanted, that would only check if the last character in the string is a non-word character.

Answer (score 19):

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that using the `g` modifier [makes the engine remember its state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results).

Try removing the `g` modifier, you do not need it anyway. The engine will always try to find a match in the whole string. Hence, the `g` modifier does not really do anything in combination with the `test` function, but is rather used for `match`. You also don't need the `i` modifier by the way, since  `\w` includes both lower-case and upper-case letters.

And one last thing. Regular expressions provide the convenient `\W` which is the opposite `\w` and thus equivalent to `[^\w]`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I dont need `g` or `i` in this case but this was just sample which i was testing as my original regex was not working. I have regex like `/[^a-d^0-3\$\-]/gi` and others which needs `g` and `i`

Comment: @NileshThakkar If you use them with `test`, why would you need `g`?

Comment: Read my answer first and then use the constructor rather than the literal notation: `var reg = new RegExp('[^\w]','gi');` http://jsfiddle.net/Kmmuy/

Comment: Use the constructor... Why?  Good advice is even better if you explain the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I got it working with Constructor, thank you @RoManiac & Stijn-de-Witt

Comment: @NileshThakkar I still doubt that you need the `g` modifier at all ;)

Comment: @m.buettner I am using match as well for some cases

Comment: @NileshThakkar fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the RegExp object is not as stateless as we think.
A quick fix is to move `var reg = /[^\w]/gi;` inside the `checkNonWordChars()` method

Best Regards,

Comment: Yes, its a quick fix but a bad idea when i am using the same expression multiple times

Comment: Alternatively, if the expression is used in various places in the script, and you don't want to create 1001 RegExp instances, `reg.compile(reg)` might work, though `compile` is considered deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have that regex global, then change it to:

```
var reg = /[^\w]/
```

It will work just as well, but not be buggy! It will be faster too, because it only needs to check for one instance of a naughty character, and you don't care about character case with non-word characters.